# How to get metrics for manifold bus in the context of aleph

Tags: clojure, metrics, manifold, aleph

Given a bus created with Aleph/Manifold, how can you measure interesting metrics like throughput, latency, number of errors and timeouts?

```
(manifold.bus/event-bus (fn []
                            (s/stream 100 )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleph has not built-in monitoring.

You could build it yourself, either in your handler function (maybe using an atom) or using Netty straight away.
There is a [`:bootstrap-transform`](http://aleph.io/codox/aleph/aleph.tcp.html#var-start-server) argument which allows you to create a Netty `ChannelHandler`.

This should allow you to use existing Netty performance monitoring solutions (this [page](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Adopters) may be useful).